# What line was cut after "nobody's perfect" from Some Like It Hot?

Tags: dialogue, some-like-it-hot

The famous last lines of [Some Like It Hot](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0053291/) are

> Jerry (removing wig): I'm a man!
>
> Osgood: Well, nobody's perfect!

However, if you watch Jack Lemmon (Jerry) carefully in [the according movie excerpt](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CYUfPTeE0DM), you can see he actually spoke one more line, though the audio cuts to the ending music so you can't hear it, just see his mouth move.

What was that line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears he doesn't actually say anything, just moves his mouth as though trying to process what has just transpired and failing to formulate a thought / comment. I think dumbfounded exasperation is more likely than an excised bit of dialogue.

From the [script](http://sfy.ru/?script=some_like_it_hot):

> JERRY
>
> But you don't understand!
>       (he rips off his wig;
>       in a male voice)
>       I'm a MAN!
>
> OSGOOD
>
> (oblivious)
>       Well - nobody's perfect.
>
> Jerry looks at Osgood, who is grinning from ear to ear,
>   claps his hand to his forehead.  How is he going to get
>   himself out of this?
>
> But that's another story - and we're not quite sure the
>   public is ready for it.
>
> FADE OUT
>
> THE END

Comment: [Trivia](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0053291/trivia?item=tr0755440): _"Well, nobody's perfect"_ wasn't actually supposed to be the last line.

Comment: It's surprisingly racy and suggestive for the time (especially considering things like the [Hayes Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_Picture_Production_Code) as it seems to suggest a happy homosexual man trying to get with an ostensibly straight man). 1959 was not an especially progressive time.